# Swap Background Images On Media Query Resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Hi i have 2 header images 1 for desktop and 1 for both tablet and mobile.

How can i swap from pc header image to the mobile / tablet header image when the screen is resized or viewed on 1 of those devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming 300px as desired width of setting:

```
#header{
background:url('first URL Here')
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    #header {
        background:url('second URL Here')
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i mark as answered perfectly. Spot on i just have to fiddle with my navigation etc constantly learning new things from you guys thanks so much.

Comment: Thank you. You can both hit top arrow (positive point) and also hit the check mark to say which answer solved your problem. These options is in left side of answers

Comment: vote up requires 15 rep lol try this 1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675029/image-uploader-and-slider